# kinsing miner fix - help needed

Tags: 16.04, permissions, apache2, cron, malware

Ineed some help removing this kinsing virus (bitcoin miner).

Currently I have this script running every 5 minnutes via a cronjob

```bsh
sudo kill $(pidof kdevtmpfsi) || True
sudo kill $(pidof kinsing) || True
sudo rm /tmp/kdevtmpfsi || True
sudo rm /tmp/kinsing || True
sudo rm /var/tmp/kdevtmpfsi || True
sudo rm /var/tmp/kinsing || True
echo "everything is good here" > /tmp/kdevtmpfsi || True
echo "everything is good here" > /tmp/kinsing || True
echo "everything is good here" > /var/tmp/kdevtmpfsi || True
echo "everything is good here" > /var/tmp/kinsing || True
sudo chmod 644 /tmp/kdevtmpfsi || True
sudo chmod 644 /tmp/kinsing || True
sudo chmod 644 /var/tmp/kdevtmpfsi || True
sudo chmod 644 /var/tmp/kinsing || True
```

But I still get an alert from the server saying:

```
Time:   Thu Feb  4 13:05:41 2021 +0000
File:   /tmp/kinsing
Reason: Linux Binary
Owner:  clipdrop:clipdrop (1001:1002)
Action: No action taken
```

I still get this error even after the script being ran, I also have locked the files.

```
sudo chattr +i /tmp/kdevtmpfsi 
sudo chattr +i /tmp/kinsing
```

Comment: 16.04 is EOL in April of this year. Can you safely copy all of your important data to an external media? I would be formatting the HDD ad install 18.04 or 20.04 as the safest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 or Ubuntu 20.04 removes the PHP7.2-FPM Exploit.